# What is the best way to check the parameters of the method?

Tags: c#, validation, parameters

I know two ways to check parameters of the method and throw exceptions when it is needed.

1) Check one each parameter and throw an exception when it is wrong:

```
public void Method(object parameter1, object parameter2)
{
    if (parameter1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter1");
    }

    if (parameter2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter2");
    }

    ...
}
```

2) Check all parameters at once and throw same exception for all:

```
public void Method(object parameter1, object parameter2)
{
    if (parameter1 == null || parameter2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    ...
}
```

The first approach is, in my opinion, better and cleaner, but also cover a lot of lines. For example, a method that actually do the 2 lines of code - in this way code will increase by 4 rows (including blank line) for each parameter.

I am interested in is the approach used by experienced programmers. Are there better ways than these two?

Comment: Personally i much prefer the first example as it explains the error much better

Comment: ArgumentNullException is much more useful when used with this construtor - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wssa019h.aspx so that you will see actual parameter name. And this forces you to use approach #1

Comment: If you wanted to do this in the older style (if/then parameter validation), its better to validate parameters individually, doing individual checks for each one. So testing of null should technically be another check from string.Length == 0. If you start having lots of validation (5 or upwards), consider having a seperate method to perform these validations and throw the exception from there. See Microsoft's advice on the subject 'Validate arguments of public methods' - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You could get the name of the parameter using reflectionand solve everything in one statement, if there are not a lot of parameters and you are using an old .NeT FW

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Updated July 2020

Check out this blog post on how you can achieve a similar approach to Code Contracts.

https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/code-contracts-vs-input-validation/

Original answer provided below

—-

If you are using .NET framework 4, check out [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992), which simplifies it down to a single line of code

```
public string Reverse(string text)
{
   Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(text!=null, "ParAmeter cannot be null.");
  
   .....
}
```

The reason you would use this is because you can now get automated tools like [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) to tell you what unit tests to apply to this method. It also gives you feedback at compile time if this method would throw an exception based on how you are calling it. Like

```
String text = null;
String reversedString = Reverse(text);
```

The compiler will warn you that this will throw an exception.

Note Code Contracts needs an add-in to be installed, but it is free.

Comment: Nice...totally forgot about them. Here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Code Contracts! I'll definitely try it.

Comment: Also to point out if you have pre-existing code like your first example and you want to begin implementing code contracts, you can tell the compiler the code block is already implemented by placing the 'Contract.EndContractBlock()' statement after it, and it will now integrate these checks automatically.

Comment: Do note that Code Contracts are effectively dead, and Microsoft [does not recommend using it for new code](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6361).

Comment: @Heinzi: Agreed. I found this blog a few months ago which is useful for anyone looking to do a similar thing. https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/code-contracts-vs-input-validation/

Answer (score 5):

Use method attribute to cleanly check your parameters.
i was wrote a framework for parameter validating in python.the c# best practice is [here](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/05/argument-validation-using-attributes.html)

Comment: Thanks for interesting link! But I think that using Code Contracts is better solution in .NET framework 4.

Comment: @mveith actually, if you look at contracts in other languages, they are implemented using attributes. Maybe this already exists in C# now, but I am not sure. Hence I found this question.

Answer (score 4):

Approach 1 is significantly more useful in my opinion.  `NullReferenceException`s, or in this case `ArgumentNullException`s thrown where you can't determine what was `null` is very frustrating.

Also, if you don't like looking at the validation code you can always wrap it in a code region and fold it away in your IDE.

Comment: I think NullReferenceExceptions are best left for when a null object is de-referenced.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I totally agree that in argument checking the `ArgumentNullException` is used to indicate a null argument.  I was just making the comparison with seeing a thrown NRE where it is ambiguous which reference is `null`.

Answer (score 4):

i know it's an old thread but i'd like to share MHO.  this is what i normally do:

create a generic method:

```
private void ValidateArgument<exType>(Func<bool> validation, string errorMessage) where exType : Exception
        {
            if (validation())
            {
                throw Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(exType), errorMessage) as exType;
            }
        }
```

and then from the calling method you do:

```
this.ValidateArgument<ArgumentException>(() => string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname), "firstname must be supplied");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is actually required.

1. If you need to throw different exceptions for both null values, then you should go for first approach.
2. If both null cases are just the same for your code, then second approach would be better readable.

Comment: *Never* catch NullReferenceException.

Comment: @HansPassant by catch I mean just to detect the error. I didnt say "or to catch error". I just made it clear what I mean in brackets. Anyway stupid of me to clarify such a silly thing. let me edit it..

Answer (score 0):

Personally I usually use methods that check or validate code and return false when they fail (and perhaps log/display an error).

I like to check all issues and validate them all, so using || would basically stop at the first test.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach is fine. Basically throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is the right thing to do here.

as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) for it says

the exception that is thrown when a **null** reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) **is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid argument.**